# $_GET not inserting into MySQL database

Tags: php

I have a small PHP script which I would like to use to add a value to an SQL table.

When I do something like:  http://ipaddress/phptest.php?350

If I just put 350 into the insert statement, it works fine. I have tried to get the result of GET to be added but seem to be unable to after many attempts.

I either get a blank, or "array" added to my table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also how would I add two values?  phptext.php?350&?450 for example?

Thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "administrator";
$password = "blabla";
$dbname = "test";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


print_r($_GET);
if($_GET["a"] === "") echo "a is an empty string\n";
if($_GET["a"] === false) echo "a is false\n";
if($_GET["a"] === null) echo "a is null\n";
if(isset($_GET["a"])) echo "a is set\n";
if(!empty($_GET[a])) echo "a is not empty";


$sql = "INSERT INTO test.sensor (VALUE) VALUES ('$_GET["a"]')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}




$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Get parameters take the following format: `phptext.php?a=350&b=450`

Comment: this topic is about grabbing url parameter. its duplicate topic

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP specification declares that GET variables are passed like the following example:

```
url.com/?bar=value&foo=value
```

So technically you're passing the GET values wrong. As I see, the correction would be:

```
http://ipaddress/phptest.php?a=350
```

Also, as an extra pointer, sanitize your variables before submitting to a SQL database, as it will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

You might want to use...

```
mysqli_real_escape_string();
```

Or use prepared statements, the more accepted/fail-safe way of working with them.

For more reference,
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php